# Converting DataSet to JSON is not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, json, dataset

I am bring data in many `Table` so I want it to convert it to json while returning it. So I tried like below

```
public static string DataSetToJSON(DataSet dset)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> parentRow = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> childRow;
        foreach (DataRow row in dset.Rows)
        {
            childRow = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dset.Columns)
            {
                childRow.Add(col.ColumnName, row[col]);
            }
            parentRow.Add(childRow);
        }
        return jsSerializer.Serialize(parentRow);
    }
```

But I am getting error at `dset.Rows`

> System.data.dataset does not contain a definition for `Rows`....

Comment: You're confusing `DataSet` with `DataTable`.

Comment: @SLaks: yes, I had the logic for `datatable`. but now I want it for `dataset` but m stuck.. :(

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, DataSets don't have rows.

Comment: @SLaks: yes, `dataset` has tables and in that it has rows..

Comment: Yes; you need to write code for that.

Comment: @SLaks: yes, i m trying..is this ok to start with `foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)` ?

Comment: If that's what you want?

Comment: probably yes, let me try if I stuck I will ping you.

Comment: @SLaks: I guess, I have done it.. I will update the answer :)

Comment: @SLaks: I have one more issue, if U dont mind can I ask here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking and doing some research and also on the guidance of `SLAKS` I finally did it.

```
public static string DataSetToJSON(DataSet ds)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> parentRow = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> childRow;

        foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
            {
                childRow = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
                {
                    childRow.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                }
                parentRow.Add(childRow);
            }
        }

        return jsSerializer.Serialize(parentRow);
    }
```

Thanks [SLAKS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks)

Comment: You probably want to make a separate object per table.

Comment: @SLaks: yes, and I did it :)

Answer (score 0):

Dataset is a collection of data tables. The rows would exist in a datatable. So you need to check the datatable in the dataset and then loop through existing columns and rows.

Try getting the first datable:

```
DataTable firstTable = dset.Tables[0];
```

If there are many data tables, then you need to loop the datatables as:

```
foreach(DataTable dt in dset.Tables)
{
  //then you can get the rows and columns values for each table as above
   foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
   {
       childRow = new Dictionary<string, object>();
       foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
       {
          childRow.Add(col.ColumnName, row[col]);
       }
       parentRow.Add(childRow);
   }
}
```